# how can i set some items to favorite items in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage, favorites

i have flutter app that contain items that i getting from firebase storage and his texts from firestore now  i want make this items like a favorite items note that i am using firebase and provider and display them in my app my question what is the logic must i do it or what is the logic that must be in my case

i am thinking about i create folder in firebase storage named favorite and move this items that i want be favorite into it and display them in my app i dont now what is the correct logic ?

i am trying to make folder in my storage firebase and move items into him then display it but don't work for me it was difficult when i want moving this items to this folder

Comment: A favorite is a many-to-many relationship between users and items.  How you implement that depends on your backend.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add a favorite attribute. ex->  class Item{  bool favorite;  Item( { this.favorite=false }) }